# How to install GPU driver on Google Deep Learning VM?

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, nvidia, google-dl-platform

I just created a Google Deep Learning VM with this image:

```
c1-deeplearning-tf-1-15-cu110-v20210619-debian-10
```

The tensorflow version is 1.15.5. But when I run

```
nvidia-smi
```

it says `-bash: nvidia-smi: command not found`.

When I run

```
nvcc --version
```

I got

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2020 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Thu_Jun_11_22:26:38_PDT_2020
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.0, V11.0.194
Build cuda_11.0_bu.TC445_37.28540450_0
```

Does anyone know how to install the GPU driver? Thank you in advance!

Update: I've noticed that if you select GPU instance, then the GPU driver is pre-installed.

Answer (score 1):

This is the guide: [Installing GPU drivers](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/install-drivers-gpu).

**Required NVIDIA driver versions**

NVIDIA GPUs running on Compute Engine must use the following NVIDIA driver versions:

For A100 GPUs:

> Linux : 450.80.02 or later
> Windows: 452.77 or later\

For all other GPU types:

> Linux : NVIDIA 410.79 driver or later
> Windows : 426.00 driver or later

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to delete the instance and create another one. Keep in mind the version compatibility [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu) and [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/cuda-compatibility/index.html). If you are installing drivers by yourself then whats the point of using pre-build instance.